# error while installing php in ubuntu

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I am trying to install php in my ubuntu system, I have already installed apache and mysql, but I am not able to install php using the following command

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 489 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-php_2%3a7.3+69+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php (2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3) ...
Setting up php7.3-common (7.3.3-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.3-common (--configure):
 installed php7.3-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.3-opcache:
 php7.3-opcache depends on php7.3-common (= 7.3.3-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.3-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.3-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php7.3:
 libapache2-mod-php7.3 depends on php7.3-common (= 7.3.3-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.3-common is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.3 depends on php7.3-opcache; however:
  Package php7.3-opcache is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.3-cli:
 php7.3-cli depends on php7.3-common (= 7.3.3-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.3-common is not configured yet.
 php7.3-cli depends on php7.3-opcache; however:
  Package php7.3-opcache is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.3-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.3-readline:
 php7.3-readline depends on php7.3-common (= 7.3.3-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.3-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.3-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.3:
 php7.3 depends on libapache2-mod-php7.3 | php7.3-fpm | php7.3-cgi; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.3 is not configured yet.
  Package php7.3-fpm is not installed.
  Package php7.3-cgi is not installed.
 php7.3 depends on php7.3-common; however:
  Package php7.3-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.3-json:
 php7.3-json depends on php7.3-common (= 7.3.3-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.3-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.3-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php:
 libapache2-mod-php depends on libapache2-mod-php7.3; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php:
 php depends on php7.3; however:
  Package php7.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.3-common
 php7.3-opcache
 libapache2-mod-php7.3
 php7.3-cli
 php7.3-readline
 php7.3
 php7.3-json
 libapache2-mod-php
 php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

While this answer is two years late, this problem can happen when `dpkg` has remnants of broken/incomplete installations in its `info` directory. You can usually solve the issue like this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/php*
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 php
sudo apt -f install
```

Then again for `libapache2-mod-php`:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php*
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 libapache2-mod-php
sudo apt -f install
```

What this is doing:

- remove the `.list` and `.md5sums` files for the affected packages from `/var/lib/dpkg/info`
- set `dpkg` to debug mode so that, if it fails to build, you'll have more specific data to work with, making it easier to find out *why* the package couldn't install
- force apt to install the packages (as much as reasonable, anyway)

Hopefully this will help someone in the future who runs into this sort of problem.